# Adding A Working Javascript Google Maps Code to Wordpress

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

I have looked at all of the posts regarding this and none of them fully address my question. Please help!

I have a working Javascript code I want to insert into my website using Wordpress.  I have looked at many different things to do, but just can't seem to figure out the correct solution.  Do I use custom fields?  Do I post this into a blog post and insert it into my homepage?

My code:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
      html, body {height: 100%; 
    margin: 1;
        padding: 1;
      }
      #map {
        height: 80%;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>

    <div id="map"></div>
    <script>

function initMap() {
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    zoom: 2,
    center: {lat: 2, lng: 1.5}
  });

  setMarkers(map);
}

var markers = [
  ['Seoul, South Korea', 37.5667, 126.9667],
  ['Pokhara, Nepal', 28.2639, 83.9722],
  ['Kunming, China', 25.0667, 102.6833],
  ['Busan, South Korea', 35.1667, 129.0667],
  ['Gwangju, South Korea', 35.1667, 126.9167],
  ['Geoje, South Korea', 34.8500, 128.5833],
  ['Toronto, Canada', 43.7000, -79.4000],
  ['Niagara Falls, Canada', 43.1167, -79.0667],
  ['Kitchener, Canada', 43.4500, -80.4833],
  ['Kathmandu, Nepal', 27.7000, 85.3333]
];

var content = ['<div id="content">'+
      '<div id="siteNotice">'+
      '</div>'+
      '<h3 id="firstHeading" class="firstHeading">Seoul, South Korea</h3>'+
      '<div id="bodyContent">'+
      '<p><b>Seoul</b> is the capital of South Korea.' +
      '<br></br><b>Adventure: </b><a href=http://mikenatalieworldwide.com/2015/06/15/hiking-korea-achasan-seoul/>Achasan Mountain</a>", '+
      '<a href=http://mikenatalieworldwide.com/2015/06/04/hiking-korea-gwanaksan-seoul/>Gwanaksan Mountain</a>, '+
  '<br></br><b>Festivals: </b>'+
  '<br></br><b>Food: </b>'+
  '<br></br><b>Places to Stay: </b>'+
  '<br></br><b>Shopping: </b><a href=http://mikenatalieworldwide.com/2015/05/05/around-seoul-namsan-tower/>Namsan Tower</a>, '+
  '<br></br><b>Sightseeing: </b><a href=http://mikenatalieworldwide.com/2015/06/25/around-seoul-jamsil-lotte-world-tower/>Jamsil Lotte World Tower</a>, '+
  '</div>',

'<div id="content">'+
      '<div id="siteNotice">'+
      '</div>'+
      '<h3 id="firstHeading" class="firstHeading">Pokhara, Nepal</h3>'+
      '<div id="bodyContent">'+
      '<p><b>Pokhara</b> is a lake-side city in Nepal.' +
      '<br></br><b>Adventure: </b>, '+
      '<br></br><b>Festivals: </b>'+
      '<br></br><b>Food: </b>'+
      '<br></br><b>Places to Stay: </b>'+
      '<br></br><b>Shopping: </b>'+
      '<br></br><b>Sightseeing: </b>'+
      '</div>', 

'<div id="content">'+
      '<div id="siteNotice">'+
      '</div>'+
      '<h3 id="firstHeading" class="firstHeading">Pokhara, Nepal</h3>'+
      '<div id="bodyContent">'+
      '<p><b>Pokhara</b> is a lake-side city in Nepal.' +
      '<br></br><b>Adventure: </b>, '+
      '<br></br><b>Festivals: </b>'+
      '<br></br><b>Food: </b>'+
      '<br></br><b>Places to Stay: </b>'+
      '<br></br><b>Shopping: </b>'+
      '<br></br><b>Sightseeing: </b>'+
      '</div>', 

'<div id="content">'+
      '<div id="siteNotice">'+
      '</div>'+
      '<h3 id="firstHeading" class="firstHeading">Pokhara, Nepal</h3>'+
      '<div id="bodyContent">'+
      '<p><b>Pokhara</b> is a lake-side city in Nepal.' +
      '<br></br><b>Adventure: </b>, '+
      '<br></br><b>Festivals: </b>'+
      '<br></br><b>Food: </b>'+
      '<br></br><b>Places to Stay: </b>'+
      '<br></br><b>Shopping: </b>'+
      '<br></br><b>Sightseeing: </b>'+
      '</div>', 

'<div id="content">'+
      '<div id="siteNotice">'+
      '</div>'+
      '<h3 id="firstHeading" class="firstHeading">Pokhara, Nepal</h3>'+
      '<div id="bodyContent">'+
      '<p><b>Pokhara</b> is a lake-side city in Nepal.' +
      '<br></br><b>Adventure: </b>, '+
      '<br></br><b>Festivals: </b>'+
      '<br></br><b>Food: </b>'+
      '<br></br><b>Places to Stay: </b>'+
      '<br></br><b>Shopping: </b>'+
      '<br></br><b>Sightseeing: </b>'+
      '</div>', 

'<div id="content">'+
      '<div id="siteNotice">'+
      '</div>'+
      '<h3 id="firstHeading" class="firstHeading">Pokhara, Nepal</h3>'+
      '<div id="bodyContent">'+
      '<p><b>Pokhara</b> is a lake-side city in Nepal.' +
      '<br></br><b>Adventure: </b>, '+
      '<br></br><b>Festivals: </b>'+
      '<br></br><b>Food: </b>'+
      '<br></br><b>Places to Stay: </b>'+
      '<br></br><b>Shopping: </b>'+
      '<br></br><b>Sightseeing: </b>'+
      '</div>',

'<div id="content">'+
      '<div id="siteNotice">'+
      '</div>'+
      '<h3 id="firstHeading" class="firstHeading">Pokhara, Nepal</h3>'+
      '<div id="bodyContent">'+
      '<p><b>Pokhara</b> is a lake-side city in Nepal.' +
      '<br></br><b>Adventure: </b>, '+
      '<br></br><b>Festivals: </b>'+
      '<br></br><b>Food: </b>'+
      '<br></br><b>Places to Stay: </b>'+
      '<br></br><b>Shopping: </b>'+
      '<br></br><b>Sightseeing: </b>'+
      '</div>', 

'<div id="content">'+
      '<div id="siteNotice">'+
      '</div>'+
      '<h3 id="firstHeading" class="firstHeading">Pokhara, Nepal</h3>'+
      '<div id="bodyContent">'+
      '<p><b>Pokhara</b> is a lake-side city in Nepal.' +
      '<br></br><b>Adventure: </b>, '+
      '<br></br><b>Festivals: </b>'+
      '<br></br><b>Food: </b>'+
      '<br></br><b>Places to Stay: </b>'+
      '<br></br><b>Shopping: </b>'+
      '<br></br><b>Sightseeing: </b>'+
      '</div>', 

'<div id="content">'+
      '<div id="siteNotice">'+
      '</div>'+
      '<h3 id="firstHeading" class="firstHeading">Pokhara, Nepal</h3>'+
      '<div id="bodyContent">'+
      '<p><b>Pokhara</b> is a lake-side city in Nepal.' +
      '<br></br><b>Adventure: </b>, '+
      '<br></br><b>Festivals: </b>'+
      '<br></br><b>Food: </b>'+
      '<br></br><b>Places to Stay: </b>'+
      '<br></br><b>Shopping: </b>'+
      '<br></br><b>Sightseeing: </b>'+
      '</div>', 

'<div id="content">'+
      '<div id="siteNotice">'+
      '</div>'+
      '<h3 id="firstHeading" class="firstHeading">Pokhara, Nepal</h3>'+
      '<div id="bodyContent">'+
      '<p><b>Pokhara</b> is a lake-side city in Nepal.' +
      '<br></br><b>Adventure: </b>, '+
      '<br></br><b>Festivals: </b>'+
      '<br></br><b>Food: </b>'+
      '<br></br><b>Places to Stay: </b>'+
      '<br></br><b>Shopping: </b>'+
      '<br></br><b>Sightseeing: </b>'+
      '</div>'
];

function setMarkers(map) {
  // Adds markers to the map.

  for (var i = 0; i < content.length; i++) {
    var marker = markers[i];
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: {lat: marker[1], lng: marker[2]},
      map: map,
      title: marker[0]
    });
   attachContent(marker, content[i]);
  }
}

function attachContent(marker, content) {
  var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
    content: content
  });

  marker.addListener('click', function() {
    infowindow.open(marker.get('map'), marker);
  });

}
    </script>
    <script async defer
        src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&signed_in=true&callback=initMap"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated!
Or a point in the right direction for me.  I have googled this tirelessly and just can't figure it out.

Thanks!
Mike

Comment: Have you tried putting the script 'src="https://maps.google..."' first? Maybe if you reference to an object called google without referencing it first, your code may not work

Answer (score 0):

You task can be done in two different ways

1) Create custom page template and assign it particular page and then enqueue your script on that page

2) Create a short-code for your map.

I would prefer the second option as you can paste shortcode in any where, so follow the below steps to create shortcode

a) add shortcode

```
add_shortcode('custom-map-shortcode','custom_map_shortcode_callback'));

function custom_map_shortcode_callback(){
   return '<div id="map"></div>';
}
```

b) Put all your js code into on file say it as map_script.js and enqueue it on the page where the short-code is present

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'enqueue_map_script' );

function enqueue_map_script(){

  global $post;

  if( is_a( $post, 'WP_Post' ) && has_shortcode( $post->post_content, 'custom-map-shortcode') ) {
      wp_enqueue_script( 'map-script', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/map_script.js');
   }

}
```

add all this code in function.php and than you can use shortcode as [custom-map-shortcode] anywhere it will display the map.

Comment: Do I add all of this above code to my funcitons.php? When I did, it didn't work

Comment: What error are you getting,
Have you added the shortcode [custom-map-shortcode]  into your page/post

Comment: Parse error. I don't get far enough to add my short code to my page

Comment: Before there was a parse code error but thats just because there was an extra ) after the custom_map_shortcode_callback, but this code is still not working.  Where can I add my api key script code?

Comment: I added it like this after the first add_action code... add_action( 'wp_head', function(){
    echo '<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOURAPIKEY&signed_in=true&callback=initMap"></script>';
});